# Troubleshooting my WebServer "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https

Some context, I'm using Nodejs and Express for my Web Server, I was using nginx but it failed for some reason and I tried to get help in a previous post but nothing.

When I connect to my site http works fine, https gets "The page isn't redirecting properly". When I connect to my site directly with it's IP it has https (ignoring the fact that it's still isn't really trusted since my certificates are linked to my domain) I just am trying to figure out where it's going wrong.

```js
const express = require('express');
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http")
const fs = require('fs')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const login = require("../modules/login")
const app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser())
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', '../public/views');
app.use( express.static( "public" ) );

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(307, { "Location": "https://www.ppealliance.com"});
    res.end();
}).listen(80);

https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync('Path to Letsencrypt Certificate'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('Path to Letsencrypt Certificate'),
    },
    app
  )
  .listen(443, () => {
    console.log(https.request)
  })

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    login.redirect(req, res)
});

app.get('/admin-login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('admin-login', { title:'Admin login'});
}); 

app.post('/admin-login-cookies', (req, res) => {
    login.cookiecheck(req, res)
});

app.get('/signup-1', (req, res) => {
    res.render('signup-1', { title:'Signup Part One'});
});


app.post('/admin-login', (req, res) => {
    login.login(req,res)
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    login.redirect(req, res)
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you think that the issue might be in the `login` module?

Comment: @robertklep No everything seems fine with the module, I tried redirecting rendering for the main page in the router and got the same result.

Comment: So your browser (?) shows that message when you open `https://X.X.X.X/`? Where does that redirect to?